# Content from two columns doesn't show as expected Django and Bootstrap 4

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm currently building a blog+portfolio with Django and Bootstrap 4.

The problem is when I try to show two columns, Articles next to my Profile. Both columns are in an HTML table, but for some reason, they do not show correctly.

For example:

[How it looks like using HTML,CSS, and Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svDM9.png)

Here is how it looks when I insert everything on my Base_layout.html

[How it looks like when it is inserted in my django Base_layout.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUzPa.png)

Here is my Base_layout, which has the code inside the table to show the articles of the blog (`{% load bootstrap4 %} {% load static from staticfiles %}` are included in the top of the document):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card mb-4" class="article-detail">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>

        </div>
      <!-- Pagination -->
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">&larr; Older</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Newer &rarr;</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="{% static 'profile.jpg' %}" class="rounded-circle card-img-top" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Leandro Fraisinet</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code that is to be shown by  Blog Entries Column 
Article_list html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

 {% block content %}


        <h1> </h1>
        {% for article in articles %}
        <div class="card-body" class="article">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ article.thumb.url}}" alt="Main post image">

           <h2 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'detail' slug=article.slug%}">{{article.title}}</a></h2>
          <p class="card-text">{{article.snippet}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <p>{{article.date}}</p>
        </div>
        <h1> </h1>
        {% endfor%}
 {% endblock %}
```

I think that my main conflict is in  Blog Entries Column  but I do not know how to solve this. 
Please any extra code that could be useful to solve this let me know.
Django version, 1.11 Phyton version 2.7, Bootstrap version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sidebar column is outside the row

```
<div class="row">
   <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
   <div class="col-md-8">

   </div>
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">

  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>
```

try to put it inside:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
   <div class="col-md-8"></div>

   <!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4"></ul>
</div>
```